# How to Create ViewModel with multiple related tables and Save Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this given the modern versions.  I have am using VS2012 MVC4 EF5 and have built a edmx file from my database.  I built a form that will allow submission of vendor information.  The main table is Vendor table that contains mainly contact information and there are additional tables that store their multiple category choices (checkbox list) and another that stores their minority info (collection of radio buttons).  So my ViewModel is the vendor table and I populate the checkboxes and radio buttons with view bags that query the lookup tables for their values.

So I assume I should either build the categories and minority parts into the ViewModel and somehow wire up the magic so that the database knows how to save the returned values or should I just use viewbags and then somehow on post read those values and loop through them to store them to the database? Either way I am stuck and don't know how to do this.

I have serached numerous examples online but none of them fit this situation.  The is not a complex data model but should be rather common real world situation.  I am new to MVC so forgive me if I am missing something obvious.

Any guidance is appreciated.

UPDATE: Here is the baseic code to save the ViewModel to the db but how do you save the checkbox list and radio buttons.  I think there are two approaches 1) to somehow include them in the ViewModel or 2) perform a separate function to save the form checkbox and radio button values.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Form(VendorProfile newProfile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            newProfile.ProfileID = Guid.NewGuid();
            newProfile.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

            _db.VendorProfiles.Add(newProfile);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ThankYou", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            PopuplateViewBags();
            return View(newProfile);
        }
    }
```

Perhaps another way of stating my problem is what if you had to build an form to where people would sign up and select all their favorite flavors of ice cream from a list of 31 flavors. You need to save the person's contact information in the primary table and then save a collection of their flavor choices in another table (one-to-many). I have a ViewModel for the contact form and a list of flavors (checkbox list) displayed from a lookup table. How do you write code to save this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: There might be a better way, but wanted to post what I discovered.  You can pass in the collection of checkboxes and then send them to another method that handles the db inserts.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Form(VendorProfile newProfile, int[] categories)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            newProfile.ProfileID = Guid.NewGuid();
            newProfile.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

            _db.VendorProfiles.Add(newProfile);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            InsertVendorCategories(newProfile.ProfileID, categories);

            return RedirectToAction("ThankYou", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            PopuplateViewBags();
            return View(newProfile);
        }
    }

    private void InsertVendorCategories(Guid ProfileID, int[] categories)
    {
        try
        {
            var PID = new SqlParameter("@ProfileID", ProfileID);
            var CID = new SqlParameter("@CatID", "");

            foreach (int c in categories)
            {
                CID = new SqlParameter("@CatID", c);
                _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec InsertVendorCategory @ProfileID, @CatID", PID, CID);
            }
        }
        catch { Exception ex; }
    }
```